# What is the recommended way to create a statistics table in DynamoDB?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'd like to store the following data attributes in DynamoDB as statistics:

```
deviceId, property, value, timestamp
```

`value` attribute changes quite frequently and needs to be saved in a new item every time it changes.

On retrieval, I'd like to query the aforementioned table to:

- get all `value` and `timestamp` for a given `deviceId` and `property`.
- get all `property`, `value` and `timestamp` for a given `deviceId`

I need retrieve these stats often.

`deviceId` is unique.

How should I create my schema? What needs to be taken into account? Is DynamoDB the best for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can’t answer if DynamoDB is best for this or not.

However, you can easily design a table to support those queries. You can use `deviceId` as your hash key, and a [compound key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-sort-keys-to-organize-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/) of property+timestamp as your range key.

To get all property, time stamp, and values for a deviceId, your query key condition expression would be

```
deviceId = :deviceId
```

To get all time stamps and values for a deviceId and property, it would be

```
deviceId = :deviceId AND begins_with(prop_timestamp, :propertyName)
```

If you’re really concerned about space, and you’re certain you won’t need any other queries, then you could choose to have only three attributes, like this

```
 deviceId | prop_timestamp             | value
--------------------------------------------------------
 38b518f5 | speed_2019-03-05T12:15:00Z | 25.3 m/s
 38b518f5 |  temp_2019-03-05T12:30:00Z | 65°F
```

If you’re not 100% certain that you won’t need any other queries, then I’d recommend including propertyName and timestamp as their own top level attributes in addition to being part of the compound range key.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! I'll come back once decided which way to go.

Comment: I think this is the way I should go to. However I'm unsure in something. My props are integers, value max of 255 (unsigned byte, char). Instead of using `begins_with` is there another function that checks for certain bits? Some kind of logic `AND`?

Comment: After a quick search I seem to have found out there are no binary operators.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is a good choice for storing a lot of data that you are not sure how to store it. but isn't optimal when we are talking on really big tables which relations as in Relational Databases.

The first question you should ask yourself, do you know all the possible properties? or there can be like 10+ unique property per device?

You can make two tables:

- **devices:** with a primary partition key device id (number), and an attribute (not part of the predefined schema) which is a list of strings that represents all the properties of the device. each query will have to start with querying this table, but the results should be retrieved very fast, and the price of storing and the ability to skip the Scan queries should suffice.
- **values:** with a primary partition key that is a concatenation of the device id and the property. and sorting key of the timestamp. the value should be an attribute.

you can also make this concatention numeric and than you can also query using `between` operator if you want to speed up things and save storage costs.

This solution may be much cheaper than Matthew's answer, but much less human readability, and maybe harder for debugging and implemention. So, I would recommend you consider both options wisely.

Also, recently Amazon have released their DocumentDB. I've no experience with this product, but from my experience with document oriented databases, it may be a good option you should check. The general idea should be with key for each device, which contains sub-collections (i think it call embedded, or nested documents) of the properties. than if you need all the properties you can query all the sub-collection of a key, and if you need specific property, you can query the sub-collection. but again, I have no experience with DocumentDB. But again, it's a new product and I don't have much have any experience, just pointing out it exists.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer! "do you know all the possible properties?" No, I dont. And, props are numbers - if that matters - and props are not unique across devices. I'll consider both answers and come back once the decision is made. 